# How to identify device uniquely?

Tags: mobile, cross-browser, unique, identity, desktop

**Firstly**, I know about the duplicates. We're not talking about iOs/Android/KindOfDevice-only, as the others & cookies are not the way I want to go.

So I want to bypass the need of a password or something by "binding" *my service* (which is only an idea by now) to the device used.
An E-Mail and stuff would be needed of course, to keep your devices bundled.

What would your approaches be?

**My thoughts so far**

- My first idea was using the mac-adress, because I heard that they're unique. But a quick google told me that's not really true.
- On Phones I could use the phone number or the IMEI, but I don't want it to be restricted to phones, it should be usable by web, too.
- I guess when we talk about a web-solution, stuff would get even more tricky because browsers won't let the service go really deep into the system and stuff?
- Of course I guess there needs to be a combination of two or more things. So two not-so-unique things combine to an 99%-unique-thing?

I just need some help about how to go on with this problem, a direction, because if you google terms like "unique device identification" you only get this medicine-thing..

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use

```
var secureUDID = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!
```

which - Returns a string created from the UUID, such as “E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F”. 
UUID - An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor.

Comment: But thats Android only?

Comment: That's iOS solution you can do it on swift/objective-c.